# How to design a scalable card game with lots of skills

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now I want to write a game like a Chinese game Legends of the Three Kingdoms. 
Player can play cards which can damage other, for a simple case, if you play a card “Kill” against the enemy, if the enemy not play a card like “Miss” he would lose on point of life.
And  if I have equipped a skill named “Reinforcement ” whose functionality is that if you make the enemy lose life, you have some probability make the enemy lost one more point of life,
If I have equipped a weapon named “Longlindao” whose functionality is that if you make the enemy lose life by card “Kill”, you can choose to remove two cards of the enemy instead of making him lose life.
There are many skills and weapons like above two, skills are not card and bind with role, weapons are same with hand cards with different functionality, most weapons can increase the attack distance.

I am not sure if you can understand the way the game plays, for more detail you can read wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legends_of_the_Three_Kingdoms.

**My question is how to design the skills, weapons and cards in a scalable way?**

My goal is to make the skill can be equipped by any role like a weapon, I can easily create many new skills and weapons while time goes by.

For example, I want make a new skill whose functionality is that if you make the enemy lose one point of life by card “Kill”, you can increase one point of life.
I want make a new skill whose functionality is that if I play a “Miss” card I can get a new card and so on.

I have a simple idea about the design.
Interfaces:

```
public interface ICommonProperties
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int AttackDistance { get; set; }
}
public interface ICommonEvents
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Before player plays card "Kill"
    /// </summary>
    void OnBeforeKill();

    /// <summary>
    /// After player plays card "Kill"
    /// </summary>
    void OnAfterKill();

    /// <summary>
    /// Before player plays card "Miss"
    /// </summary>
    void OnBeforeMiss();

    /// <summary>
    /// After player plays card "Miss"
    /// </summary>
    void OnAfterMiss();

    /// <summary>
    /// Trigger if lose life or increase life
    /// </summary>
    void OnLifeChange();

    /// <summary>
    /// Tigger if role is dying
    /// </summary>
    void OnDying();
}

public interface IRole : ICommonProperties, ICommonEvents
{
    int CurrentLife { get; set; }
    int MaxLife { get; set; }
    List<Card> CardsInHand { get; set; }
    List<IWeapon> BaseWeapons { get; set; }
    List<ISkill> BaseSkills { get; set; }
}

public interface IWeapon : ICommonProperties, ICommonEvents
{
    int AttackDistance { get; set; }
}

public interface ISkill : ICommonProperties, ICommonEvents
{

}
```

Implement the interfaces:

```
public class BaseRole : IRole
    {
        public BaseRole()
        {
            this.CurrentLife = 3;
            this.MaxLife = 3;
            this.Name = "BaseRole";

        }

        #region Fileds
        public int CurrentLife
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int MaxLife
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public List<Card> CardsInHand
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public List<IWeapon> BaseWeapons
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public List<ISkill> BaseSkills
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int AttackDistance
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        #endregion

        public virtual void OnBeforeKill()
        {

        }

        public virtual void OnAfterKill()
        {

        }

        public virtual void OnBeforeMiss()
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnAfterMiss()
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnLifeChange()
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnDying()
        {
            //If role is dying, he can ask medicine called "Yao" to gain one more life point.
        }



    }

    public class BaseWeapon : IWeapon
    {
        public BaseWeapon()
        {
            this.AttackDistance = 1;
            this.Name = "BaseWeapon";

        }
        public int AttackDistance
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual void OnBeforeKill()
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnAfterKill()
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnBeforeMiss()
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnAfterMiss()
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnLifeChange()
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnDying()
        {
        }
    }

    public class BaseSkill : ISkill
    {
        public BaseSkill()
        {
            this.Name = "BaseSkill";
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int AttackDistance
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual void OnBeforeKill()
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnAfterKill()
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnBeforeMiss()
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnAfterMiss()
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnLifeChange()
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnDying()
        {


        }
    }

    public class Card
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Whether it can be used to attack others, such as "Kill" card CanAttack=true, card "Miss" CanAttack=false
        /// </summary>
        public bool CanAttack { get; set; }

    }
```

Real role, weapon and skill:

```
   public class XiangyuRole : BaseRole
        {
            public XiangyuRole()
            {
                this.Name = "Xiangyu";
                this.MaxLife = 4;
                this.CurrentLife = 4;
                // The role equip skill QinglingSkill by default.
                this.BaseSkills = new List<ISkill>();
                this.BaseSkills.Add(new QinglingSkill());

                this.BaseWeapons = new List<IWeapon>();
                this.BaseWeapons.Add(new RemoveCardsWeapon());
            }
        }

        public class RemoveCardsWeapon : BaseWeapon
        {
            public RemoveCardsWeapon()
            {
                this.Name = "RemoveCardsAfterWeapon";
                this.AttackDistance = 1;
            }

            public override void OnAfterKill()
            {
                //If you make the enemy lose life, you can remove two cards of the enemy instead of losing life.
            }
        }

        public class QinglingSkill : BaseSkill
        {
            public QinglingSkill()
            {
                this.Name = "GetACardAfterMiss";
            }

            public override void OnAfterMiss()
            {
                //if you play a "Miss" card, get a new card
            }
        }
```

**My problem**

A role can equip several skills and different weapons at the same time, there may trigger many events at once you play a card. 
Then how to control the events provided by different skills and weapons? They may be exclusive and may not, and how to control the trigger order of the events?
Is there a better way to achieve the goal?

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I would use more interface segregation. One interface per possible event (instead of methods on ICommonEvents). Then use Publish-Subscribe on a "game" object to handle the events. Let each "card" be notified of all events but only handle those that it care about.

Comment: Hi Antwerpen, I want the skill to looks like a "game object" and can be placed on any role just like placing an object on the role object, just think about one requirement: the skills can be sold on the game store, players can equip the skills on any role, how do you solve this?